# SQL Functions with passing variable

Tags: postgresql

this is my PostgreSQL  query. Here I pass hard coded merchant id (merchant_id = 11).but I need to dynamical pass one merchant id from set of merchant id list. but I don't Know how to pass id as a variable or array  by using PostgreSQL  function.

```
   select s.enabled from loyalty_scheme L 
JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) WHERE ((SELECT demoting_time_period from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11)GROUP BY scheme_id)< to_char((SELECT (DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE::date) - DATE_PART('year', (select max(t.date_time) As maxdat FROM loyalty_scheme L 
JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id = ( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11)GROUP BY scheme_id) ) )) ::date)) * 12 +
(DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE::date) - DATE_PART('month', (select max(t.date_time) As maxdat FROM loyalty_scheme L 
JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id = ( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = 11)GROUP BY scheme_id) ) ))::date))),'FM999MI'))
```

here is other query to find list of  merchant id

```
select array_agg(DISTINCT merchant.merchant_id)
        from merchant
```

this are the id Array {3,6,7,11,23,32,34,40,41,43}

**in first code I hard coded 11,but i need to pass all those id one by one.Is any one know how to do it. please help me to do this**

Comment: you can use cte or subquery for value and then join it, thus to change the value you will have to edit one place, like `select s.enabled from loyalty_scheme L join (select 11 as v) def on true ....where merchant_id = def.v`

Comment: sorry,I need to pass id one by one dynamically

Comment: and what you do with result?.. otherwise just copy/paste(replace)

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the the way to do this

here is my CODE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getdata()  RETURNS CHAR AS $enables$ DECLARE enables CHAR;  my_arry INTEGER[] := (
       select array_agg(DISTINCT merchant.merchant_id)
        from merchant
    ); BEGIN FOREACH my_arry SLICE 1 IN ARRAY my_arry    LOOP select s.enabled  INTO enables from loyalty_scheme L  JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid) JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) WHERE ((SELECT demoting_time_period from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = ANY(my_arry) )GROUP BY scheme_id)< to_char((SELECT (DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE::date) - DATE_PART('year', (select max(t.date_time) As maxdat FROM loyalty_scheme L  JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid) JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id = ( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = ANY(my_arry) )GROUP BY scheme_id) ) )) ::date)) * 12 + (DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE::date) - DATE_PART('month', (select max(t.date_time) As maxdat FROM loyalty_scheme L  JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid) JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) where (T.unipoint_customer_ref_id = ( select unipoint_customer_ref_id FROM subscribe_merchant where schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id from loyalty_scheme where minimum_purchase_amount =(SELECT min(minimum_purchase_amount) from loyalty_scheme where merchant_id = ANY(my_arry))GROUP BY scheme_id) ) ))::date))),'FM999MI')) ;

END LOOP; RETURN enables; END; $enables$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```